# How to get the least value and summation per element

Tags: python

i have l = [["abc-123, def-456, ghi-789"],["jkl-101112,mno-131415,pqr-161718"]]

summation per low value is that possible
already tried to split string on this but fail to do so. anyone can help

Comment: What do you want, your question is not clear.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output?

Comment: output = abc-123, jkl-101112 and a result of 101235

Comment: @ppd2021 please edit your questions via additing your comment `output = abc-123, jkl-101112 and a result of 101235` to your question's text body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
l = [["abc-123, def-456, ghi-789"],["jkl-101112,mno-131415,pqr-161718"]]
summat=0 #=== Sum of all numbers
neat_list=[]
min_sum=0
for d_ in l:
    sum_list=[] #=== All numbers added and then the minimum is found. Gets reset with every iteration
    list_summat=0 #=== List of all number in that list. Gets reset with every iteration.
    for dw in d_:
        d=dw.split(",") #==== Split by a comma
        for d__ in d:
            new_l=d__.split("-") #==== Split by a -
            new_l[-1]=int(new_l[-1]) #==== Convert the last element into an integer.
            summat+=new_l[-1] #=== Add sum
            sum_list.append(new_l[-1]) #==== Add number to sum list
            list_summat+=new_l[-1] #=== Add to the list number of that list.
    print("List: ",d_)     
    print("Sum of all integer elements in the list: ",list_summat)
    print("Least number in the list: ",min(sum_list))
    min_sum+=min(sum_list)
    for j in d:
        if str(min(sum_list)) in str(j).strip():
            neat_list.append(j) 
    print("-----------------------------------")

print("Sum of all integer elements: ",summat)
print("The least elements in the lists: ",neat_list)
print("Sum of all integer elements in 2 least elements: ",min_sum)
```

Output:

```
List:  ['abc-123, def-456, ghi-789']
Sum of all integer elements in the list:  1368
Least number in the list:  123
-----------------------------------
List:  ['jkl-101112,mno-131415,pqr-161718']
Sum of all integer elements in the list:  394245
Least number in the list:  101112
-----------------------------------
Sum of all integer elements:  395613
The least elements in the lists:  ['abc-123', 'jkl-101112']
Sum of all integer elements in 2 least elements:  101235
```

Comment: output = abc-123, jkl-101112 and a result of 101235

Comment: @ppd2021, You want to sum the least 2 elements?

Comment: yes and the least value of each element that will look like this- abc-123, jkl-101112